# Logistic regression not producing an s-shaped curve

Tags: logistic-curve

I am trying to create a model that shows on the y axis a range from 0-1 and get that distinctive binary dependent variable s-shaped curve, yet I am not able to get it with the following code.

```
logit_model <- glm(leave ~ years_education + trust_politicians + 
                   years_education + eu_integration + income,
                   data = ess, 
                   family = binomial(link = "logit"))
eduprofiles <- data.frame(
 years_education = seq(from = 0, to = 53, length.out = 54),
 trust_politicians = mean(ess$trust_politicians), 
 income = 0, 
 eu_integration = mean(ess$eu_integration), 
 country_attach = mean(ess$country_attach)
eduprofiles$predicted_probs <- predict(logit_model, 
    newdata = eduprofiles, type = "response")   
plot(predicted_probs ~ years_education, data = eduprofiles, 
    xlab = "Years of Education", 
    ylab = "Probability of voting for leave", 
    col = "LightSkyBlue", type = "l", frame.plot = FALSE, lwd = 3)
```

I feel like I am overlooking something obvious, but I can't seem to figure out what. What do you all think?
the plot shows: [image]

Comment: What does the plot show?

Comment: just added the plot!

Comment: My guess is years_education has a negative coefficient and you need to expand the range of the x axis below zero to see the S shape.

Comment: Or expand the y-axis to 0 to 1.

Comment: That being said, the model shown by expanding the axes beyond the sampled data may not be meaningful.

Comment: why is income set to zero?  Did you mean-centre it already?

Comment: The leave rate in your data set is low, so it is impossible to get the predicted probability to close to 1. If you really want to see the S shape, extend the age to - 200.

Comment: income is a dummy variable meaning someone makes either below or above the median income of a country

Answer (score 4):

As commenters have pointed out, you're not plotting enough of the range of the x-axis to see the "expected" sigmoid shape.  In your particular example you'd have to extend the education variable to take on *negative values* - the predicted probability at 0 years of education (already a rather unrealistic value in a modern society!) is only about 0.22. (50 years of education is also pretty unrealistic ...)

In fact, you could be even worse off (in a sense) - if your predicted probabilities were in the range from 0.3 to 0.7, the logistic curve would actually look almost *linear* (not just non-sigmoid).

Comment: that absolutely helped me move forward, I increased the range and saw the sigmoid shape. Thank you so much!

Comment: if this solves your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...